# ast matcher for unused return value

Tags: c, function, return, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to match functions that have return values, but are not used. Something like this:

```
int foo(int a) { return 0; }

int main(void) {

foo(5); -->> replace with (void) foo(5);

return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write an ast-matcher that matches foo(5); and pastes a (void) in front when I use -fix with clang-tidy.

I am kind of lost. I know functionDecl() will give me all the functions, but how can I check if the return value of that function is used?
I couldn't find something with clang-query.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: I am looking for unused return values. It is a think at my place.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to match not function declarations, but call expressions instead. Deconstructing this problem we get the following: we need to match all call expressions that call for functions returning *something* and not being used as an operand somewhere.

The first condition is pretty straightforward. However, the second one can have many different variations as *used return value* can appear in AST in many-many ways:

- operand of some other expression
- return value
- initializer for variable declaration
- condition in `if`/`while`/`do while`/`for`/`switch` statements

Maybe there are some other cases that I didn't think of.

Putting it all together without the last case:

```cpp
callExpr(callee(functionDecl(unless(returns(voidType())))),
         unless(hasParent(anyOf(expr(), returnStmt()))),
         unless(hasParent(varDecl())))
```

For the conditions in different statements, there is no conventional way to check that, so a new matcher should be implemented.

```cpp
#include <clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h>

template <class... Other>
bool isCondition(const clang::Expr *Node, const clang::Stmt *Parent);

template <class ConditionalNode, class... Other>
inline bool isConditionImpl(const clang::Expr *Node,
                            const clang::Stmt *Parent) {
  if (const auto *AsConditional = llvm::dyn_cast<ConditionalNode>(Parent)) {
    return AsConditional->getCond() == Node;
  }

  return isCondition<Other...>(Node, Parent);
}

template <class... Other>
inline bool isCondition(const clang::Expr *Node, const clang::Stmt *Parent) {
  return isConditionImpl<Other...>(Node, Parent);
}

template <>
inline bool isCondition(const clang::Expr *,
                        const clang::Stmt *) {
  return false;
}

AST_MATCHER(clang::Expr, isInCondition) {
  auto &Context = Finder->getASTContext();
  auto *Parent = Context.getParents(Node)[0].get<clang::Stmt>();
  if (Parent == nullptr) {
    return false;
  }
  return isCondition<clang::DoStmt, clang::IfStmt, clang::ForStmt,
                     clang::SwitchStmt, clang::WhileStmt>(&Node, Parent);
}
```

Including this new matcher we can use the following matcher:

```cpp
callExpr(callee(functionDecl(unless(returns(voidType())))),
         unless(hasParent(anyOf(expr(), returnStmt()))),
         unless(hasParent(varDecl())),
         unless(isInCondition()))
```

It is most likely that this solution can be rough around the edges in some cases including implicit casts, but it can give you an idea.

Happy hacking with clang!